# C++ memory deallocations on Java heap producing SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, swig, new-operator, delete-operator

I'm trying to implement the method described [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Java.html#Java_heap_allocations) and [here](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/usenix07/posters/sorensen.pdf) which override `new` and `delete` in a SWIG module in order to allocate memory on the Java heap instead of natively.

I added the SWIG prescription to my interface file. It compiles fine, and when I run my Java GUI, I can see from `cout` statements that it appears to be `new`ing and `delete`ing without problems for a while (over 100k times). Eventually though, I always get this (same stack trace):

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff8754c0e0, pid=61178, tid=81411
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_60-b27) (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.60-b23 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsystem_platform.dylib+0x50e0]  _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Haswell+0x1c0
```

Using my `cout` statements, it looks like the sample code is using the same addresses inside `delete` as it used in `new`, so the code itself appears to be working. There are no known memory issues with my code (I've analyzed it using AddressSanitizer and Valgrind), and furthermore, if I comment out only the `cached_jvm = jvm;` line (which results in the code using malloc/free instead of on the JVM heap), then it works ok. I'm not running out of heap memory -- for my testing I'm using small sample data.

If I switch the `ReleaseByteArrayElements` line to use mode `JNI_ABORT` instead of `0`, then the free does not fail in the same place, but other problems occur afterwards which I didn’t bother to figure out.

Why is it segfaulting? Are there certain kinds of memory operations that are not compatible with this approach? I'm not using malloc/free (directly). I'm linking to a 3rd party library in C++, and they might be up to something.

Here's a sample compile line:

```
/usr/bin/clang++   -DEngine_EXPORTS -m64 -W -Wall -Wconversion -Wshadow -Wno-error=shadow -fdiagnostics-show-option   -Wno-sign-conversion -stdlib=libc++ -ftemplate-depth=1000 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -funroll-loops -dynamic -fPIC -fno-common -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -Werror -Wno-error  -fno-strict-aliasing -g -fPIC -I/third/party/include -I/my/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers     -o CMakeFiles/Engine.dir/engineJAVA_wrap.cxx.o -c engineJAVA_wrap.cxx
```

Stack trace:

```
Thread 59 Crashed:: Java: Thread-22
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff902fbf06 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff98e704ec pthread_kill + 90
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff95c736df abort + 129
3   libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010a282beb os::abort(bool) + 25
4   libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010a3a6a2a VMError::report_and_die() + 2304
5   libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010a3a6d9b crash_handler(int, __siginfo*, void*) + 106
6   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff8754952a _sigtramp + 26
7   ???                             000000000000000000 0 + 0
8   libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010a27d0b1 os::print_location(outputStream*, long, bool) + 917
9   libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010a283d89 os::print_register_info(outputStream*, void*) + 83
10  libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010a3a588c VMError::report(outputStream*) + 2142
11  libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010a3a6522 VMError::report_and_die() + 1016
12  libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010a284816 JVM_handle_bsd_signal + 1131
13  libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010a280a7b signalHandler(int, __siginfo*, void*) + 47
14  libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff8754952a _sigtramp + 26
15  ???                             0x0000000000000001 0 + 1
16  libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010a11d830 jni_ReleaseByteArrayElements + 124
17  libengineEngine.jnilib          0x000000012750e41b JNIEnv_::ReleaseByteArrayElements(_jbyteArray*, signed char*, int) + 75 (jni.h:1689)
18  libengineEngine.jnilib          0x000000012750e1f8 operator delete(void*) + 408 (engineJAVA_wrap.cxx:298)
19  libengineEngine.jnilib          0x000000012750f710 Java_engineJNI_delete_1VectorMol + 80 (engineJAVA_wrap.cxx:586)
20  ???                             0x000000010ad9e954 0 + 4477020500
21  ???                             0x000000010ad90c4d 0 + 4476963917
22  ???                             0x000000010ad90c4d 0 + 4476963917
23  ???                             0x000000010ad90c92 0 + 4476963986
24  ???                             0x000000010ad90c4d 0 + 4476963917
25  ???                             0x000000010ad90c4d 0 + 4476963917
26  ???                             0x000000010ad90c4d 0 + 4476963917
27  ???                             0x000000010ad90c4d 0 + 4476963917
28  ???                             0x000000010ad909d0 0 + 4476963280
29  ???                             0x000000010ad90c92 0 + 4476963986
30  ???                             0x000000010ad897a7 0 + 4476934055
31  libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010a0eab0e JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) + 1710
32  libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010a0eb29c JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*, KlassHandle, Symbol*, Symbol*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) + 356
33  libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010a0eb448 JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*, Handle, KlassHandle, Symbol*, Symbol*, Thread*) + 74
34  libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010a145965 thread_entry(JavaThread*, Thread*) + 124
35  libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010a3612d3 JavaThread::thread_main_inner() + 155
36  libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010a3629ce JavaThread::run() + 450
37  libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010a28343a java_start(Thread*) + 246
38  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff98e6d99d _pthread_body + 131
39  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff98e6d91a _pthread_start + 168
40  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff98e6b351 thread_start + 13
```

Edit:

I found that if I comment out all my `.delete()` calls (SWIG generated method) in my Java code, then I get a different error:

```
#  SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x00007fff95c7379f, pid=85146, tid=80651
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_60-b27) (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.60-b23 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsystem_c.dylib+0x5e79f]  __abort+0xb1
```

and `SIGILL` is a new one to me...

Comment: The code described in your link makes the invalid assumption that Java will never move the underlying byte array. Astonishing that it ever worked, if indeed it ever did, and even more astonishing that it got published under the IBM banner.

Comment: @EJP, maybe memory accessed by GetByteArrayElements is not supposed to be moved by Java until ReleaseByteArrayElements is called, but it certainly seems like something along these lines is happening when I run it.